# Kibana 7.x how to count full text instead of each word in visualize

Tags: elasticsearch

My chart aggregation terms count the only word in the message instead of the full text

Ex: message: "word1 word2 word3"

I want it counts full message, the result returns the count for "word1", "word2"...

I turned on the [fielddata](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html)

here is how my field looks like

```
"mes" : {
  "type" : "text",
  "fields" : {
    "keyword" : {
      "type" : "keyword",
      "ignore_above" : 256
    }
  },
  "fielddata" : true
}
```

Comment: Can you show the aggregation query you're running?

Comment: I used the visualized pie chart. the Metric: aggregation.count. In the buckets, aggregation.terms, field.mes, order by: Metric.count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was I could not select the mes.keyword from visualizing mode (it didn't appear). There are many data in the Elastic logstash so they can't work properly.

I create a [separated space](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/master/xpack-spaces.html) for my log. Now they are all Ok. I can select field mes.keyword and it counts the full text.